# webrtc: how to simulate slow connections?

Tags: windows, webrtc

I am looking for a way to test some webrtc on SLOW internet connections.

Any idea on how to limit my bandwith on Windows ?

I tried a couple of softwares without success (fiddle, clumsy) without success.

Comment: Try NEWT, I haven't tried it myself but heard good things about it - https://blog.mrpol.nl/2010/01/14/network-emulator-toolkit/

Answer (score 0):

can't service-worker could add delay and/or drop randomly some packet ?
i'm looking for something like that here : [How to slow down a service-worker to simulate 56k or 2G 3G slow connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65485346/how-to-slow-down-a-service-worker-to-simulate-56k-or-2g-3g-slow-connection)